# objective c check string suffix from character set

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to check the suffix of a string against a character set but I'm getting errors:

```
if ([string hasSuffix:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"(+-*/"])
```

What am I doing wrong, is there a correct alternative?

Comment: What error you getting ? your code missing one right bracket , that is the only error I found

Answer (score 8):

`-[NSString hasSuffix:]` takes an `NSString` as its argument, not an `NSCharacterSet`. Your best bet is probably to call `-[NSString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:]` with `NSBackwardsSearch` as an option and check that the location is at the end of the string.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'll just use three OR statements, seems easier

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to see if the first letter of your string is one of the characters from the set.  If so, then use this:

```
NSCharacterSet *set =  [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"(+-*/"];
if ([[string substringToIndex:1] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound)
    // String starts with one of the characters from the character set
```